# Java application recklessly consuming memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

For a project I am working on, I was tasked with creating a way of converting an image into a non-cryptographic hash so it could be easily compared with similar images, however I ran into an issue where the JVM would begin to recklessly consume memory, despite the Java Monitoring & Management Console not reporting any increase in memory consumption.

When I first ran the application, the Task Manager would report values like this:
[image: Task Manager]
However after only about 30 seconds, those values would have doubled or tripled.

I used the JMMC to create a dump of the process, but it only reported around 1.3MB of usage:
[image: Eclipse MAT]

The strangest part to me is that the application performs an operation which lasts for about 15 seconds, then it waits for 100 seconds (debug), and it is during the 100 seconds of thread sleeping that the memory used doubles.

Here are my two classes:

ImageHashGenerator.java

```
package com.arkazex.srcbot;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImageHashGenerator {

    public static byte[] generateHash(Image image, int resolution) {
        //Resize the image
        Image rscaled = image.getScaledInstance(resolution, resolution, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        //Convert the scaled image into a buffered image
        BufferedImage scaled = convert(rscaled);
        //Create the hash array
        byte[] hash = new byte[resolution*resolution*3];
        //Variables
        Color color;
        int index = 0;
        //Generate the hash
        for(int x = 0; x < resolution; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < resolution; y++) {
                //Get the color
                color = new Color(scaled.getRGB(x, y));
                //Save the colors
                hash[index++] = (byte) color.getRed();
                hash[index++] = (byte) color.getGreen();
                hash[index++] = (byte) color.getBlue();
            }
        }
        //Return the generated hash
        return hash;
    }

    //Convert Image to BufferedImage
    private static BufferedImage convert(Image img) {
        //Create a new bufferedImage
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        //Get the graphics
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        //Return the image
        return image;
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
package com.arkazex.srcbot;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Create a hash
        byte[] hash = ImageHashGenerator.generateHash(ImageIO.read(new File("img1.JPG")), 8);    //Memory grows to around 150MB here
        System.out.println(new String(hash));
        try{ Thread.sleep(100000); } catch(Exception e) {}    //Memory grows to around 300MB here
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The program stopped growing to 300MB after a few seconds for no apparent reason.  I had not changed anything in the code, it just stopped doing it.

Comment: "Reckless" meaning "I don't know why it's grabbing that memory"? Unless it's growing to fill max space I wouldn't call it a "leak" per se; I tend to either (a) chalk it up to the JVM doing what the JVM does, or (b) dig deeper using a profiling tool.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: @immibis I was running it from within eclipse, but even when I tried to run it as an exported jar file, it still had the over consumption issue.

Comment: Take a heap dump and run eclipse MAT

Comment: *"I had not changed anything in the code, it just stopped doing it."* -- Hmm ... it probably just garbage collected :-)

Comment: @OldProgrammer That's what I was doing, but it only reported about 3MB of allocated memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you missing here is that some of the image classes use off-heap memory.  This is (presumable) invisible to the JMMC because it only gets told about on-heap usage.  The OS-level memory usage monitoring sees it ... because it is looking at the total resource consumption of the JVM running your application.

The problem is that the off-heap memory blocks are only reclaimed when the corresponding on-heap image objects are finalized.  That only happens when they are garbage collected.

> The program stopped growing to 300MB after a few seconds for no apparent reason. I had not changed anything in the code, it just stopped doing it.

I expect that the JVM decided it was time to do a full GC (or something like that) and that caused it to free up lots of space in the off-heap memory pool.  That meant the JVM no longer needed to keep growing the pool.

(I am being deliberately vague because I don't actually know how off-heap memory allocation works under the covers in a modern JVM.  But if you want to investigate, the JVM source code can be downloaded ...)

Answer (score 0):

See the explanation in the `/** comments */`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Create a hash

        /** Here it allocates (3 * resolution^2 )bytes of memory to a byte array */
        byte[] hash = ImageHashGenerator.generateHash(ImageIO.read(new File("img1.JPG")), 8);    //Memory grows to around 150MB here

        /** And here it again allocates the same memory to a String 
        Why print a String of 150 million chars? */
        System.out.println(new String(hash));
        try{ Thread.sleep(100000); } catch(Exception e) {}    //Memory grows to around 300MB here
    }
}
```

Comment: Even when I remove the `System.out.println(new String(hash));` code, the application still consumes the same amount of memory. (As reported by the Task Manager)

Comment: @NicholasHollander ok, then it's not the issue, thanks for checking.